# Why alert() executes even though preventDefault() is called before alert()?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, event-bubbling

In the following code, why the `alert('Alert on btn is triggered') })` fires, even though `event.preventDefault()` is called before this line in the `click` handler of the `#btn` el.

Also, why `onclick="alerted()` does not fires on `#btn` or on `#wrap` div but the callback fires attached to `click` with `addEventListener` fires.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn')
var wrap = document.getElementById('wrap')

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  event.stopPropagation()
  if (event.cancelable) {
    event.preventDefault()
  }
  alert('Alert on btn is triggered')
})


function alerted() {
  alert('Alerted fired')
}

wrap.addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert(this.id)
  alert(event.target.tagName + "#" + event.target.id)
})
```

```css
#wrap {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap" onclick="alerted">
  <button id="btn" onclick="alerted">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The `alert` isn't the *default* action of the event, so naturally preventing the default doesn't have any effect on the `alert`. Moreover, nothing in the DOM event system can terminate a JavaScript function in the middle. JavaScript functions run to completion.

Comment: except a return @T.J.Crowder :p

Comment: @JaromandaX - `return` **is** a completion.

Comment: good point @T.J.Crowder - i didn't read your comment fully :p

Comment: @T.J.Crowder "The alert isn't the default action of the event," then what is the default action for a button

Comment: @appu - Your `button` element has the default `type`, which is `"submit"`. A submit button that isn't in a form has no default action on `click`. If it were in a form, it would submit the form.

Answer (score 6):

Calling `event.preventDefault()` or `event.stopPropagation` will not stop the callback currently in progress. *No matter* the context of a function, if it starts running, the only way to stop it from continuing is to explicitly `return`.

If you want to make sure the rest of the function stops running when `preventDefault()` is called, change to:

```
  if (event.cancelable) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return;
  }
```

It would also probably be a good idea to define `event` as the argument that the handler takes, rather than relying on the implicitly global `window.event` (which, although it *works* in some browsers, is [not a great idea to use](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event#Browser_Compatibility)).

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn')
var wrap = document.getElementById('wrap')

btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation()
  if (event.cancelable) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return;
  }
  alert('Alert on btn is triggered')
})


function alerted() {
  alert('Alerted fired')
}

wrap.addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert(this.id)
  alert(event.target.tagName + "#" + event.target.id)
})
```

```css
#wrap {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap" onclick="alerted">
  <button id="btn" onclick="alerted">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: unfortunately, first chrome, and now I think even Firefox, have adopted this once microsoft specific non-standard global event rubbish :p

Comment: @JaromandaX - And they (Mozilla) held out soooooo long. :-) But [it's specified now](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-window-extensions), like many legacy bits of rubbish the web is stuck with for compatibility. I'd like to think that browsers would start issuing deprecation console messages when it's used, but...

Answer (score 1):

Explanation: the alert is not default in your click event, calling `event.preventDefault();` or not will will trigger the alert anyway.

`preventDefault()` depends on the default event. Example: using `preventDefault()` on click event will prevent clicking trigger or using `preventDefault()` on keydown will prevent the default keyboard pressing down event.

Just like the current answer, to prevent the alert, use `return;`

Also, I just noticed, your code `onclick="alerted"` should be `onclick="alerted()"`

**UPDATE:**

Explanation 1: The alert won't fire in the `btn` because it was prevented. you put `alerted()` on `onclick` and the `click` event was prevented.
In other words, alert is inside click, click was prevented so the alert will not fire.

Explanation 2: Button is an object not an event, objects can have the same events. Example: divs are container but you can use click event on them.

Comment: `onclick="alerted()` corrected that. But still `alerted()` does not fire on clicking the button or div. Can u plz explain, Why?

Comment: `the alert is not default in your click event` then what is the default for a button

Comment: Also, this is quite confusing, because you use  `onclick=""` in HTML even though you already used `addEventListener` on JavaScript.

Answer (score -2):

Because when the event fires even if you stop his propagation it will not fire in other event listeners but your function will continue to execute.